# Use environments feature vs separate orchestrators for production and test

Tags: uipath, uipath-orchestrator

What's the best setup if you have multiple system like DEV, TEST, PROD with orchestrator?

Do you have one orchestrator for all and split robots with environment or do you have a separete orchestrator for each system.

Comment: If you use it for private purpose you could create 3 accounts. For each environment one account. If you only need 2 of them, that could work with one account as you can install Studio with 1 licence on 2 machines.

Comment: Not for privat....

Comment: Qe bought it but there are diffent possibility for setup. Some use enviroments for seperating system and others have totally separeted systems. Who do you have orchestrator for TEST, DEV and PROD?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more convinient to have all environments in one orchestrator but in this case you need to use a paid version

Comment: convinient is not a reason:-) I need facts to compare